# Created my own Farenheit-to-Celsius converter. Why doesn't it work though?

Tags: javascript, function

Ok, so here's the code.

HTML:

```
      <input id="cel" onkeyup="conversion('celsius')"> degrees Celsius<br>
  equals<br>
  <input id="far" onkeyup="convert('farenheit')"> degrees Fahrenheit<br>
```

Here's the Javascript that's linked to the html page via "src" attribute:

```
var celsius = document.getElementById('cel').value;
var farenheit = document.getElementById('far').value;


function conversion(celsius, farenheit){
  if (celsius == true){
    var cels2far = celsius * 1.8 + 32;
    return cels2far
  } if (farenheit == true) {
    var far2cels = (farenheit - 32) * 5/9;
    return far2cels
  }
};
```

I want it to immediately convert the numbers as soon as the user inputs it into the text field. I went over it a few times and made a few changes, but I don't know why it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the arguments you passed. One is always `undefined`, the other is always a string. However, you’re checking whether both are `true` or `false`. Also, `conversion` or `convert`, what’s the name of the function?

Comment: You're also only reading the values out when the page first loads (into variables that conflict with the function parameter names), not when the function runs.

Comment: If `celsius` is a string, `celsius == true` will never return true

Comment: AND you have the _same variable name_ for the fields’ values and the passed arguments. And you do arithmetics to strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your function conversion takes two parameters, and you seem to be expecting them to both be booleans. But you are calling it with one parameter, which is always a string.

You are also overriding the global variables 'celsius' and 'farenheit' (i.e. the ones you defined outside of the function) by reusing those names.

Also, because you retrieve the values of the cells outside of the function, they will only get set when the page first loads, and then will never update again; you need to re-retrieve the cell values every time you call the conversion function.

Also, when you retrieve the "value" attribute of any HTML element, it will always be a string, so you have to convert it to a numeric data type (which my example code below does using the 'parseFloat' function).

Your function is also merely returning the result of the conversion, when you actually need it to be placing the result back into the HTML.

Try this:

```
function conversion(tempType){
  var celsius = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cel').value);
  var farenheit = parseFloat(document.getElementById('far').value);

  if (tempType == 'celsius'){
    var cels2far = celsius * 1.8 + 32;
    document.getElementById('far').value = cels2far;
  }
  if (tempType == 'farenheit') {
    var far2cels = (farenheit - 32) * 5/9;
    document.getElementById('cel').value = far2cels;
  }
}
```

That was a lot of changes, but don't take it too negatively! Learning to code is a lot of trial and error. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Browser_compatibility) instead of your `onkeyup=""` attributes that is a [best practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_coding_practices) for javascript.

Also you could verify that user inputs only numbers but i think is not needed at this point.

```js
var celsius = document.getElementById('cel');
var farenheit = document.getElementById('far');

celsius.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if(!isNaN(this.value)) //<-- only numbers
    farenheit.value = (this.value * 1.8) + 32;
});

farenheit.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  if(!isNaN(this.value))
   celsius.value = (this.value - 32) * 5/9
});
```

```html
<input id="cel"> degrees Celsius<br>
equals<br>
<input id="far"> degrees Fahrenheit<br>
```

But if you still want to use your code, it needs a couple tweaks, here's working:

```js
var celsius = document.getElementById('cel');
var farenheit = document.getElementById('far');

function conversion(tofarenheit){
  if (tofarenheit) {
    farenheit.value = celsius.value * 1.8 + 32;
  } else {
    celsius.value = (farenheit.value - 32) * 5/9;
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="cel" onkeyup="conversion(true)"> degrees Celsius<br>
equals<br>
<input id="far" onkeyup="conversion()"> degrees Fahrenheit<br>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For your first script, you added ".value" to the variable. That's just so you make sure it comes out as an integer?\

Comment: `.value` retrieves the input's value as a `string`. In order to check if a string contains pure numbers or not you need the method [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the fields values within your function, else it allways will be null or whatever default value you have

```
function conversion(kind){
  if (kind == 'celsius'){
    var cels2far = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cel').value) * 1.8 + 32;
    return cels2far
  } if (kind == 'farenheit') {
    var far2cels = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('far').value) - 32) * 5/9;
    return far2cels
  }
};
```

Also, as you are passing a string as the first argument to the function, celsius will allways be set and farenheit never. So change this too.

When working with calculations in javascript, allways make sure to `parseFloat` or `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are setup wrong. The function should only accept one parameter so it would look like `function conversion(type)` and then the conditions would look like `if(type === 'celsius')` and the other would be `else if(type === 'farenheit')`